# What is the different between state hook vs assign to local variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

Coming from class-based object-oriented language C#, I can assign an object to a local variable so I can use it later. But in this example, when I assign it to a local variable, it will not render. When I console log the `tempPersonObj` inside the handleClick, it will print the object. But it will print empty object inside the `PersonDetails` function.

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const persons = [
  { 
    "name": "Arto Hellas", 
    "number": "040-123456",
    "count": 3,
    "id": 1
  },
  { 
    "name": "Ada Lovelace", 
    "number": "39-44-5323523",
    "count": 10,
    "id": 2
  },
  { 
    "name": "Mary Poppendieck", 
    "number": "39-23-6423122",
    "count": 17,
    "id": 3
  }
]

const PersonDetails = ({person}) => {
  console.log(person)
  return (
    <div>
      <p>-----------------</p>
      <p>{person.name}</p>
      <p>{person.number}</p>
      <p>{person.count}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {

  const [view, setView] = useState(false)
  const [personObj, setPersonObj] = useState({})
  let tempPersonObj = {};

  const handleClick = (person) => {

    //This will work
    // setPersonObj(person)

    //This will not work
    tempPersonObj = person
    console.log(tempPersonObj)

    setView(true)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List:</h1>
      {persons.map((person) => {
        return (
        <div key={person.id}>
          {person.name} {""}
          <button onClick={() => handleClick(person)}>View</button>
        </div>
        )})
      }

    {/* This will work */}
    {/* {view && <PersonDetails person={tempPersonObj}/>} */}

    {/* This will not work */}
    {view && <PersonDetails person={personObj}/>}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

React components work by rendering UI as a function of state and props. The `tempPersonObj` local variable is neither state nor props and is redeclared each render cycle.

In other words, you can mutate `tempPersonObj` in the `handleClick` callback and it will update, but when the `setView(true)` state update is processed and the component rerenders, `tempPersonObj` is redeclared an empty object. It's a completely new variable unrelated to the `tempPersonObj` from the previous render cycle.

```
const App = () => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false);
  const [personObj, setPersonObj] = useState({});

  let tempPersonObj = {}; // new variable each render cycle

  const handleClick = (person) => {
    //This will work
    // setPersonObj(person)

    //This will not work
    tempPersonObj = person
    console.log(tempPersonObj) // <-- see object mutation

    setView(true)
  }

  return (
    ...

    tempPersonObj // empty object again on next cycle

    ...
  );
}
```

If you need to update a `person` object it necessarily needs to be part of React state so it is retained from render cycle to render cycle.

```
const App = () => {
  const [view, setView] = useState(false);
  const [personObj, setPersonObj] = useState({});

  const handleClick = (person) => {
    setPersonObj(person);
    setView(true);
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```